# How can I throw an exception in a Java web project that can't be caught and which ends execution?

Tags: java

If I have a function that does not throw an exception in its signature, but which reaches a condition that should stop all execution, is it possible to throw some kind of exception without altering its signature and that of all calling functions? I tried using response.sendError(500,"My Error"), but it occurs to me that that may not stop execution.

For example, I have coded often in PHP to exit + some small output, but I read that that stops the entire server in Java.

Comment: don't think you can, without stopping the JVM. After all: catch(Exception busted) will deal with that.

Comment: Probably you have to throw RuntimeException: `throw new RuntimeException("Some message");`

Comment: @Kartic Thanks. See my comment on the checked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw RuntimeException or its subclass.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the question, but a developer had told me that RuntimeException was "unchecked" and that meant that it did nothing if you didn't catch it. How sad. I get them all the time in Android, and I've verified that they work with Java Web also.

Comment: Indeed RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions: you may throw them in your code but you don't need to catch them or add to method signatures. But still they are exceptions and the execution will stop if one occures.